# How do I return multiple columns with the RETURN keyword with a cypher query in apache age

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

In the following code, it's a simple query that fetches nodes that has the specified relation

```
test=# SELECT *
FROM cypher('first_graph', $$
MATCH (a:Person)-[]->(b:Person) RETURN a.name, b.name
$$) as (v agtype);
```

When I ran the query I get the following error

```
ERROR:  return row and column definition list do not match
LINE 2: FROM cypher('first_graph', $$..
             ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are returning more than 1 columns from cypher query, you need to specify exact number of columns outside the query.

```
test=# SELECT *
FROM cypher('first_graph', $$
MATCH (a:Person)-[]->(b:Person) RETURN a.name, b.name
$$) as (v agtype, w agtype);
```

The above query will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

To return multiple columns for the above cypher query, you have to specify the number of columns to be returned as `agtype` values and not just a column.

Hence, the following query should give you the expected number of columns:

```
test=# SELECT *
FROM cypher('first_graph', $$
MATCH (a:Person)-[]->(b:Person) RETURN a.name, b.name
$$) as (u agtype, v agtype);
```

For more information about the `RETURN` statement and its uses, click [here](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/clauses/return.html#return-all-elements).

Answer (score -2):

You always need to add the same number of agtypes at the `RETURN` clause to match the `RETURN` values inside your cypher query